# Remove payment details and shipping Method Name in the invoice template?

Tags: magento-1.8, email, sales, email-templates

I need to remove some of the details under Payment Method in my Invoice emails:

```
Country of IP
xxx

Debit type
xxx

Card numbers
xxx

Validity date
xxx
```

and I also need to remove the shipping **Method Name** from my invoice as well, from

```
Shipping Method:
Standard Delivery (free if 12+ bottles) - bestway
```

to

```
Shipping Method:
Standard Delivery (free if 12+ bottles)
```

in my invoice template, I can see these codes,

payment methods,

```
<td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #f4f1ea; border-bottom:1px solid #f4f1ea; border-right:1px solid #f4f1ea;">
                                {{var payment_html}}
 </td>
```

shipping,

```
  <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #f4f1ea; border-bottom:1px solid #f4f1ea; border-right:1px solid #f4f1ea;">
                                {{var order.shipping_description}}
                                &nbsp;
 </td>
```

But where are `{{var payment_html}}` and `{{var order.shipping_description}}` located?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the payment information, just remove `{{var payment_html}}` and its parent element from the template. You may also need to remove other `<td>` elements to make it look good, but for starters try it like that.

As for the shipping method name, that is shown as it is shown in the checkout process.
If you want it without `- bestway` then you should change the name of the shipping method.
I don't know how you can do that. I guess it's different from method to method (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need some of the data from `{{var payment_html}}` - like `Standard Delivery (free if 12+ bottles)`, I just need to remove the Method Name. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid that if you remove the payment method from the e-mail template it will be removed everywhere (order view page for example). Each payment method has (should have) its own template for rendering the data that is used everywhere.

Comment: I don't mind removing it from everywhere.

Comment: As for `{{var payment_html}}` I actually need to keep `Processing date` and remove the rest of the details that I listed out in my question above - is it possible?

Comment: You just need to edit the template for the payment method. And that one depends on each payment method. Each payment method should have an info block associated to it. See the value of the variable `$_formBlockType` in the payment model. Now look for that block and you should see inside it the template name that renders the block. You need to modify that.

Comment: Thanks. What about removing `best way`? Where can I find it?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas on that one. I hope half an answer is better than no answer.

Comment: lol yes half is better than none :-)